# WSO2 APIM Can we set different access/refresh token expiration time for each application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

From WSO2 APIM document here [Access Token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Working+with+Access+Tokens), there are configurations for **default** expiration time of access token and refresh token. However, can we set different expiration time of them separately for each applications?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure different expiration time for different application through configuration. But, through the API Store when generating new token, you can provide the expiration time through UI.

Comment: Thanks Abimaran. I understand that in API store we can set only the expiration of **Application** token generated via API Store UI only but there is no way to specify the expiration time of **Application User** access token differently for each application (end user authentication via oauth2). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link[1] to see how to set the validity time for an application access token from the API Store UI.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-Renewingapplicationaccesstokens

Comment: Thanks VizZy. I understand that this apply only for **Application** token generated via API Store UI only but there is no way to specify the expiration time of **Application User** access token differently for each application. Am I correct?